# route packets through hardware loopback interface, not lo

Tags: linux, hardware, route, loopback

My embedded Linux board has 3 interfaces:

- eth0 - For all outbound traffic
- eth1 - A hardware loopback (traffic leaves board, but comes immediately back in the same port)
- lo - Standard loopback interface

`ifconfig` reveals the following:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF  
          inet addr:169.254.1.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1561 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1561 (1.5 KiB)
```

And, `route` yields:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
A.B.C.96        *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         A.B.C.110       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I can `ping` the eth1 interface's assigned IP, like so:

```
PING 169.254.1.1 (169.254.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 169.254.1.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.143 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.1.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
```

But, ***all*** of the packets appear on the `lo` interface, not eth1, according to the `ifconfig` reported RX/TX counters.

Why?  Is the traffic ***really*** ingressing and egressing the `eth1` port, but being accounted under the `lo` interface?  Or, is the traffic really all flowing through `lo`?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46448/6622

Answer (score 1):

Local traffic doesn't go through Ethernet interfaces. Fundamentally, local traffic goes through the local interface. The OS has no idea that your eth1 interface has hardware loopback.

Comment: thanks!  That's what I also suspected, so why is all the traffic aimed at 169.254.1.1 going through lo instead of eth1?

Comment: Because it's local traffic.

Comment: it is not generally true indeed.  if you ping some local IP - yes it goes to LO. however all local traffic that goes inside host with docker containers do NOT go to lo indeed.  it depends of actual case not in general.

Answer (score -1):

Linux TCP/IP stack is very flexible one. See:

```
# — let's add dummy IP-address to Wi-Fi NIC
# ip ad ad 11.1.2.3/24 dev wlan0
# — Now chage its scope from 'local' to 'link'
# ip ro replace 11.1.2.3 dev wlan0 scope link table local
```

…

```
# — with tcpdump we can see now that's traffic to that dummy
# ex-local IP-address actually tries to go out of Wi-Fi NIC:

00:15:22.807607 ARP, Request who-has 11.1.2.3 tell 10.0.0.7, length 28
```

Comment: Thanks, poige, but I don't understand what any of those lines are doing, much less, why.  Sorry.

Comment: @Trevor, comments added, and you can use `ip help`, `ip ad help` or `ip ro help` to become familiar with `ip` tool. Also, google for LARTC — Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO.